# How can I make an online Book like http://www.20thingsilearned.com/

Tags: javascript, flash, html, animation

Recently, I have found this site made by Google Team.

http://www.20thingsilearned.com/

So far I understand this is not based on Flash. How can I use this technology to make an online book using their technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked in the usual spots to see if there's a framework or something but I only found these two things (it looks like it would be a TON of work to use):

news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1918551 >>> gist.github.com/705761

Alternatively you might want to look into the slides at http://slides.html5rocks.com.

They have a Google Code project page at code.google.com/p/html5rocks/wiki/Slides where you can download the source for that.

**EDIT**
check this out!
http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js

and this!
http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/

Comment: Check this out too: http://cykod.github.com/CoderDeck/?utm_medium=email#slide-0

Answer (score 4):

This is HTML5. You can check the explanation here: http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip.html :)

Or if you want you can do it with jQuery Booklet too though not as smooth as HTML5, see here: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/MoleskineNotebook/

Answer (score 2):

They posted the source code for the whole app (running on Google App Engine) under GPL v2 at http://code.google.com/p/20thingsilearned/ so you can reproduce the whole book effect too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is not flash for sure but flash or flexx can also be used for developing this. This is developed using HMTL 5 and javascript. HTML 5 is having a canvas object and the i believe it is using properties of canvas to bulid it. However if you will search for some jQuery book plugins then also you may get some similiar results.

Comment: Thank you so much. I use this one  http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/ 
which is using jQuery but not so smooth as it is in  http://www.20thingsilearned.com/.